# Nine speed derailleur on 10 speed cassette

Tags: road-bike, derailleur, derailleur-rear

Will combination work? I have 10 speed shifters, 10 speed chain, 10 speed cassette and all components are Shimano.

The reason I ask is because I am new to cycling and I am having trouble indexing my gears. Gears skip and I get some catching. It just might be not indexing properly or it might be the combination.

From a comment:

> It’s a road bike but decided to go flat bar initially from a comfort aspect, hence the reason for the Tiagra flatbar shifters - 10 speed. All components are new, frame is second hand, hanger is straight from what I can tell. Cassette is 10 speed Ultegra, derailleur 105 9 speed, chain is a 10 speed SRAM. It’s a mix and I would have gone all 105 10 speed but I bought it aftermarket from a bike shop, and I am only making sense of the components now.

EDIT: Take delivery of the Tiagra RD 4700 tomorrow.Will let everyone know how it goes.

Comment: Incidentally, this is almost exactly the situation I'm working through now, with 105 9 speed GS mech, and a sunrace 10 speed 11-32 cassette.

Comment: It’s a pain. Variables variables variables but some helpful folk here  Let me know how you go

Comment: I have no answer - my 9 speed rear mech was slightly bent, and while it worked perfectly on the small cogs, gears 5-9 were clattery and wanted to change, but gear 10 (32 tooth) was okay probably cos it was up against a limit stop.   So I ended up replacing the mech with a brand new 10 speed 105 GS unit, and it works great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have Shimano components, it depends if you have an MTB or road groupset.

Shimano used the same actuation ratio (ratio of cable length pulled to lateral movement of derailleur cage) for road 8, 9 and 10 speed systems then changed for 11 speed. Theoretically a 9 speed derailleur will work with a 10 speed shifter and cassette.

On the MTB side the change to a different actuation ratio was made at 10 speed, so a 9 speed MTB derailleur will not work with a 10 speed shifter and cassette.

A well known exception is road Tiagra 10 speed 4700 series which uses a road 11 speed actuation ratio (although I'm not sure that it's exactly the same, a Tiagra 4700 10 speed derailleur may not work with a 105 5800 or Ultegra 6800 group.)

Indexing is not too hard to get right (if you have matching shifters and derailleurs of course). Park Tool has a [good page](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment) that explains how it works.

If you cannot get the indexing right at both ends of the cassette you may have another problem. A bent derailleur hanger is a common culprit. Cables hanging up in the housings is another.

If the chain is skipping over sprocket teeth rather than ghost shifting you likely have worn sprockets.

Comment: Thanks mate. First time on the forum and you have been a champ . It’s a road bike but decided to go flat bar initially from a comfort aspect, hence the reason for the Tiagra flatbar shifters - 10 speed. All components are new, frame is second hand, hanger is straight from what I can tell. Cassette is 10 speed Ultegra, derailleur 105 9 speed, chain is a 10 speed SRAM. It’s a mix and I would have gone all 105 10 speed but I bought it aftermarket from a bike shop, and I am only making sense of the components now. Any further advice you could give with the additional information? Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. If you have Tiagra 4700 flat bar shifters, that's your problem. You need matching 4700 shifters and derailleurs (front and rear). Any 10 speed chain and cassette is OK though.

Comment: FYI Shimano publishes [extensive specs and compatibility info](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/). Road rear drivetrain compatibility is [here](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-454). Search for 4700 and you'll see it does not have any cross-group compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for your help. People’s generosity surprise me sometimes. You think getting matching shifters would be the cheapest / easiest option? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: You'll need Tiagra 4700 derailleurs. 4700 is the only 10 speed group that has flat bar shifters.

Comment: Thanks Argenti 

Answer (score 1):

As to your latter question within your comments, Shimano has [Tiagra 4600 flatbar shifters](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tiagra-4600/SL-4600.html) which will pull the correct amount of cable to correctly move the nine speed 105 derailleur. 
Another option would be to change to a nine speed cassette which would allow you to use shifters from Shimano's mountain bike side as well.  Deore, XT, SLX, and XTR are the names of the upper tiers of mountain groupsets from which to choose these shifters (Tiagra level is equivalent to Deore or XT).  You wouldn't necessarily have to change your ten speed chain or front drivetrain as the slightly thinner ten speed chain will work fine on the nine speed cassette.  The increased risk of the thinner, ten speed chain jamming in a nine speed system is greatest at the front chainrings (10s chain with 9s crankset), so in this case, the mix is especially ok in practice as I'm assuming you're running a ten speed crankset.

Comment: Thanks Jeff  Got a few options now